# shoppingcart newbie. do I have to buy or can I build

Tags: paypal

im starting to look into building my first ecommerce site.  my customer wants to use paypal.  ive been doing some reading on the paypal site re their different apis and ive noticed that they have listed a bunch of shopping carts that they work with.   up until this point I was thinking about building my own shopping cart.  but maybe ive over simplified the solution in my head.
I was thinking that I would have to keep track of a session for each customer. .. And store their purchase selections in session variables.
can someone with some shopping cart experience shed some light on thd pros and cons of building your own cart vs. buying?
thanks

Comment: use any open source/closed source ecommerce software

Comment: thanks Tamil.   I was hoping for some explanations as to why I should go one way or anotjer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building your own cart is a great way to learn that how things are done but it takes lots of time. I know because i did the mistake that writing my own code from zero.
I suggest you to download some open source ecommerce systems and read their libraries. There are tons of codes already working great you wouldnt want to invent the wheel again.